# Using getJSON to populate animated responsive image grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to pull images from my flickr feed and use them to fill an animated responsive image grid.
Plugin information here:
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/08/02/animated-responsive-image-grid/

I am able to get the needed information using getJSON and I am formatting it in the way the plugin requires, but the grid won't format itself.

The resulting data looks like this, which is what the plugin should read:

```
<div id="ri-grid" class="ri-grid ri-grid-size-1 ri-shadow ri-grid-loading">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="[Image Link]></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src=[Image Link]></a></li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

I know this formatting should work because I tried it by putting the links directly in the HTML and it worked perfectly.  However, when I use getJSON to put the information in the HTML (since I want the page to update itself when the Flickr feed is updated), the plugin doesn't seem to put the pieces together.

Here is the JSON request I am using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?id=109059624@N04&lang=en-us&format=json&jsoncallback=?", function(data){
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
      $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#ri-grid")
        .wrap('<li><a href="#"></a></li>');
    });
    $("#instagrams").children().wrapAll('<ul />');
  });
</script>
```

And this is the script I use to create the grid:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function() {

            $( '#ri-grid' ).gridrotator( {
                w320 : {
                    rows : 3,
                    columns : 4
                },
                w240 : {
                    rows : 3,
                    columns : 3
                }
            } );

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: invalid html inserting `<LI>` into a `DIV`, and then try wrapping later with `UL`

Comment: Is there a way to append all the <li> elements into a pre-existing <ul> tag?

Comment: sure...change selector to the ul instead `"#instagrams ul"`

Comment: That didn't seem to change the output. The script is creating the correct HTML code, but the plugin doesn't seem to be compiling it when the HTML page creates the code

Comment: need to initalize plugin after html is inserted...within callback of getJSON. AJAX is asynchronous...so takes time to get data. Or if plugin accpets data pass it in through plugin API

Comment: so add the $("ri-grid).gridrotator() function within the same script as the getJSON?  Rather than have it in it's own script later in the HTML?

Comment: if the plugin needs the html to be there...yes. WHere you call it now, it will run before the html from AJAX is created

Answer (score 0):

This plugin is designed to read static HTML that is already loaded in the DOM. Your JSON request is taking a bit longer to load to the DOM so you'll probably need to do a callback on the plugin to run after you've received your JSON data. You could probably cheap out and try putting a settimeout on your plugin load, which should allow the JSON request enough time to load the HTML, and then operate on the data in the DOM properly.